# placement of widgets in kivy when useing a BoxLayout and no absolute coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to create a view of some parameters. A parameter has a name, a description and a value.This should look like:

parameter name, slider, numeric display

description

in kivy you can use a BoxLayout in the kv language:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Label:
            text: 'warp power'
        Slider:
            id: pwSlider
            min: 0.0
            max: 1.0
            value: 0.0
        TextInput:
            text: "%.4f" % pwSlider.value
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: pwSlider.value = float(self.text)
    Label:
        markup: True
        text: '[color=a0a0a0]sets the warp power[/color]'
```

The problem is, that the description and paramter name does not start at the same x position.
A other problem ist, that I want to scale the text x-size down to the size of the text inside.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To restrict a label width to the texture width (same logic for height if you need), you can:

```
Label:
    size_hint_x: None
    width: self.texture_size[0]
```

If you use a such label in a BoxLayout, it will be left/bottom aligned by default. For your information, you can use `pos_hint` to place it somewhere else.

I guess in your example, just using the method described above in your description Label will be enough.

Comment: do you know how to arrange the position of the text? In this example it is centered. To build a nice UI it would be perfect if it is aligned to the left. The idea is that 'warp power' and 'sets the warp power' start at the same x-position.